# CasperJS click event not working

Tags: casperjs

I have some basic automated tests running with CasperJS on a ecommerce store but am having problems with one particular click method. The click is on an add to cart button with an onclick() event and however I try I cannot get it to work with CasperJS.

I am evaluating if it works or not by checking for a div on the page, one that is only present once the button has been clicked (i.e product has been added to cart). I have also forced navigation to the cart page and have confirmed the product has not added.

The button looks like this:

http://..../ajax_cart/add/');">Add to Bag

The CasperJS click method looks like this:
this.click('button.btn-cart');

It is added with AJAX so I originally suspected that the AJAX didn't have time to add so have also tried adding a wait() but it makes no difference.

Is this likely to session related, AJAX related or something else?

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this.click('button.btn-cart'); is going to work for anything.  You should look to include the **xpath** variable in the top of the script. this is in the documentation for casperjs.

Once you have that, right click on the element using chrome and copy xpath.

then in casperjs,

```
casper.then(function () {
    casper.click(x('paste_xpath'));
});
```

Comment: Hi there, I have similar problem. On my page, there is a radiobutton list. When I change radio button (using Chrome), ajax call is created and the page is updated. I copy and paste radiobutton xpath, and I call Casper's click function and then I make screenshot. In screenshot I can see that radio button is selected, but screen is not updated. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me. Using Capser's Click method with CSS selectors worked for me on another part of the website, but not on the part I'm working on now, so it was really frustrating troubleshooting this. I tried with XPath and it works like a charm!